# kotlin, which function is called in the base class's init block

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

having a base class and Child derived from it:

```
open class Base(var data: String) {

    init {
        doInit()
    }
    open protected fun doInit() {
       data += " in Base doInit()"
    }
}

class Child(data: String): Base(data) {

    init {
        doInit()
    }
    override fun doInit() {

        data += super.doInit() + " in Child doInit()"
    }
}

val obj = Child("child")
```

in Child("child"), the Base's init{} is called. which `doInit()` the Base's init{} is supposed to call, from the Base's one or the Child's one?

Comment: First of all the function can't be overriden and class can't be extended until it is marked as `open`, secondly you are concatenating `Unit` that is returned from super with a String which is not possible because there is no plus operator defined for Unit class.

Comment: This might help https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22044

Answer (score 1):

If we define classes like this:

```
open class Base(var data: String) {

    init {
        doInit()
    }

    protected open fun doInit() {
        data += " in Base doInit()"
        println("in Base doInit()")
    }
}

class Child(data: String): Base(data) {

    override fun doInit() {
        data += " in Child doInit()"
        println("in Child doInit()")
    }
}
```

and create a child object:

```
val obj = Child("child")
```

we will see the output:

> in Child doInit()

So when creating a child object and calling a function in base class that is overridden in child class, the child's function is called. That's called [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

Comment: the base's init{} is called before the child instance is finishing the creation (is it?), does it have the child' override function be able to call? if there is init{} also in child, seems only after it is called then the override function is ready.

Comment: If we also add logs to `init{}` of Base and Child classes we will see next printed sequence: 1. Base init{}  2. in Child doInit()  3. Child init{}.  The answer to your questions is yes. `if there is init{} also in child, seems only after it is called then the override function is ready.` - I don't know what do you mean by `ready` but as we see Child's overriden function can be called before `init{}`